# If $f(x) \in C^1$ then number of maxima is finite in any interval.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am wondering if the following statement is true.

> If  $f(x) \in C^1$ (not-constant) then a number of maxima are finite in any finite interval.

Here the set $C^1$ means that on the domain of $f$ we have that
\begin{align}
\sup_{x \in dom(f(x))} |f(x)|<c_0<\infty,\\
\sup_{x \in dom(f(x))} |f^{'}(x)|<c_1<\infty,
\end{align}

Comment: In fact you can have uncountably many maxima in an interval with a $C^\infty$ function that is nonconstant in every subinterval

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand completely your question, but perhaps the following function is a counterexample: take $\displaystyle f(x)=\int_0^x t\exp(-t^2)\sin(1/t)dt$ (defining the function under the integral sign to be $0$ if $t=0$). Then $f$ is bounded, $f^{\prime}(x)=x\exp(-x²)\sin(1/x)$ is bounded, but as $f^{\prime}(1/k\pi)=0$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, $k\not =0$, and that the derivative change sign in these points, on $[-1,1]$, $f $ has an infinite number of (local) maxima (and of minima)

Comment: Thank you for your example. This is exactly what I was looking for.  Do you know of any sufficient condition on function and its derivatives for the number of extreme points to be finite on a finite interval?

Comment: One can introduce hypothesis, such as the function has the form $P(x)\exp(-x^2)$, where $P$ is a polynomial (the exponential is here for your condition that the function and its derivative are bounded), but a general sufficient condition, I do not know....

Comment: What if the second derivative is bounded too?

Comment: I think that  if you replace in the counter-example $x\exp(-x^2)\sin(1/x)$ by  $x^n\exp(-x^2)\sin(1/x)$ with $n$ large, you can have the second derivative bounded, but the counter-example works with this new function.

Comment: Ok. One more. What about an analytic function?

Comment: If you have an analytic function on all of $\mathbb{C}$, say $f$, and if you take the restriction of $f$ to any intervall of $\mathbb{R}$, then as its derivative is again analytic, it has a finite number of zeros in any compact, so you have a positive answer.

Comment: Great. Can you provide a reference for this?

Comment: Any book on analytic functions gives you these results. Sorry, I must go....Bye

Comment: @Boby You may want to take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem

Answer (score 1):

By interval do you mean a finite interval. If not, the statement is not true. Counter example would be $sinc(x)$ on $(0,\infty)$

Comment: yes. Finite. Interval.

Comment: Sin[1/x] has infinite maxima on (0,1), where Cos[1/x] = 0, that is 
1/x = pi/2+k pi with integer k  --> x = 2/((2k + 1) pi)